# How to fetch an <img> tag which is inside an anchor <a> tag

Tags: jquery, html

I want to retrieve the  tag which is inside an anchor tag.

```
<pre>
  <a some properties>
    **<img src="" width="" height="" />**
  </a>
</pre>
```

I need to get whole `<img>`.

What I am doing is:

```
if($(img_ads[k]).has("img").length) {
    console.log ($(img_ads[k]).children('img'));
}
```

It returns this:
[Output of above Jquery code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuS3I.png)

Please suggest some simple alternative which can output the contents of image tag as simple text or HTML.

Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$('a').html()` this will give you the `<img src="" width="" height="" />` in text format

https://jsfiddle.net/ugeshgupta000/nzeb0zuy/